# C++ - Pthread how to send in value

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

How do I send in a `std::string` into my thread?

This is my code:

```
void* sendReminder(void*) 
{
    system("echo 'hello' >> buffer.txt");    
}

int main()
{
    string str1 = "somevalue";
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &sendReminder, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the value in as a `void*` in the last argument to `pthread_create`. Inside the thread function, you cast the `void*` back to the type of the object that you passed in. In this case a string.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i pass it in as void*

Comment: See @pb2q answer for a specific example. That is a good way to do it in your example case

Answer (score 5):

Use the fourth argument to `pthread_create` to send an "argument" to your function, just be sure to make a copy of it on the heap:

```
string *userData = new string("somevalue");    
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &sendReminder, (void *) userData);
```

If you'll be using `pthread_join` to wait on the new thread(s), suspending execution of the caller, you can get away with just passing an address of the local variable:

```
if (pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &sendReminder, (void *) &str1) == 0)
{
    pthread_join(t1, &result);
    // ...
```

You can retrieve the value with:

```
void* sendReminder(void* data) 
{
    std::string* userData = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(data);
    // Think about wrapping `userData` within a smart pointer.

    cout << *userData << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is a good model to use. Allocate a new object to hold the information you want to pass to the thread, pass the thread a pointer to that object, and have the thread free/delete the object when it's done with it.

Comment: after i send it in , how do i get the value of userData inside the function.

Comment: @user1578897 see the edit for using the string on the thread-side

Comment: but if i cout userData, it still return the memory address, how do i get back the original value.

Comment: @user1578897 did you get this to work? note that in `sendReminder`, `userData` is still a pointer to the `string` object and will need to be dereferenced with `*`. See the edit in the answer.